# How to run multiple functions from a select element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a simple tool for some folks in my workplace. I am trying to run different functions depending on option values picked from a html select element. And I am stuck... please dont laugh.Just got back into coding 3 weeks ago.how i want this to work is the user clicks to lower dropdown menu... selects an option... then is asked for adding additional input, then that with some predefined text is added to a text area.then then the menu resets. Please make answers as simple as possible.

```
<!-- BEGIN ROUTING DROPDOWN MENU -->

  <select id="routingdropdownmenu">
  <option value="">MAKE A SELECTION</option>
  <option value="1">ROUTE TO STORE</option>
  <option value="2">ROUTE TO WAREHOUSE...</option>
  <option value="2">CANCEL SHIPPING</option>
  <script>
  var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
  var mydropdown = document.getElementById('routingdropdownmenu');
  mydropdown.onclick = function(){
  var INVOICE = prompt("WHAT IS THE INVOICE NUMBER?");  
  if (INVOICE != null) {
  if (mydropdown = 1) {
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO       STORE ";}
  else
  if (mydropdown = 2) {
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO    WAREHOUSE ";}
  else
  if (mydropdown = 3) {
  mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + "CANCELLING SHIPMENT";}
  this.value = "";
  </script> 
  </select>

<!-- END ROUTING DROPDOWN MENU -->
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle or snippet...

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you lost your element whose id is `REMARKSTEXTAREA`
2. You need bind a `onchange` function not `onclick`
3. You need to use `mydropdown.value` to get selected values
4. You need to use `==` not `=` to do the switches .

---

Html

```
<input id="REMARKSTEXTAREA" />
<select id="routingdropdownmenu">
    <option value="">MAKE A SELECTION</option>
    <option value="1">ROUTE TO STORE</option>
    <option value="2">ROUTE TO WAREHOUSE...</option>
    <option value="3">CANCEL SHIPPING</option>
</select>
```

---

javascript

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('routingdropdownmenu');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
var INVOICE = prompt("WHAT IS THE INVOICE NUMBER?");  
if (INVOICE != null) {
   if (mydropdown.value == 1) {
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO       STORE ";
    }
   else  if (mydropdown.value == 2) {
   mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO    WAREHOUSE ";
   }
   else  if (mydropdown.value == 3) {
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + "CANCELLING SHIPMENT";
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How useful would this really be in a real work environment if you don't know enough to do this part?

Anyways, the change event will trigger the select's event handler. Event handler will only accept an input in the text input and will prompt for one until one is entered or cancel button is clicked in which case it quits all together.

Using a switch and the `selectedIndex` of the select determines what is printed in the output element.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var text = document.getElementById('invNum');
var menu = document.getElementById('routeMenu');
menu.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var INVOICE = text.value;
  while (INVOICE == 'undefined' || INVOICE == '' || INVOICE == null) {
    if (INVOICE == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      INVOICE = prompt("Enter Invoice Number First");
    }
  }

  var out = document.getElementById('out');
  var opt = menu.selectedIndex;
  switch (opt) {
    case 1:
      out.textContent = " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO       STORE ";
      break;
    case 2:
      out.textContent = " ROUTING INVOICE " + INVOICE + " TO    WAREHOUSE ";
      break;
    case 3:
      out.textContent = "CANCELLING SHIPMENT";
    default:
      return false;
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Route Menu</legend>
  <label>Invoice Number
    <input id='invNum'>
  </label>
  <select id="routeMenu">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">Route to Store</option>
    <option value="2">Route to Wharehouse</option>
    <option value="3">Cancel Shipping</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <output id='out'></output>
</fieldset>
```